# Search bookmark tag in Chrome browser address bar

Tags: google-chrome, search, tags

I'm using Chrome now after a long long time fan of FireFox, and I really miss the FF addon/feature when I type something in the address bar, it automatically shows up the bookmark site that has the tag matched with what I've typed.

**In Chrome it also shows up, but in the order that I don't understand how it is, and the bad thing is some site DOES have the tag, but not appearing in the list.**

Is there any Chrome extension that automatically list all the bookmarks that have the tags matched with I am typing?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I have made on extension that can solve my mentioned problem already.
For anyone that wants to try:

After installing this extension, at the omnibar, type letter a (for my convenience) and then space or tab, and start typing the key words.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ghvil2chj6cnhmp/omni.crx?dl=1